# Cordova ionic-google-autocomplete keyboard flicker when swipe up the results

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, autocomplete, keyboard

I'm using the `ion-google-autocomplete` plugin in my Cordova app for address lookup.

The problem is that when I activate an input box to bring up the autocomplete control and type a few letters to get the autocomplete results listed underneath and then swipe up the result list, the onscreen keyboard starts to flicker, like keeping going up and down very quickly.

I've made a video for this: http://youtu.be/peCmv2J1nzA

Edit:

Adding the markup here

```html
<input type="text" id="addressAutoComplete1" name="addressAutoComplete1" google-autocomplete-suggestion location="data.location" locationAsText="data.locationAsText" country-code="AU" on-selection="onAddressSelection(location, locationAsText)" ng-model="LocationTextToDisplay" placeholder="Add location" required class="wrap-month"/>
```

When user taps on this input box, the autocomplete control is shown in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Why can't you show some code?

Comment: @Mayank Just added the code.